# How to count number of comparisons and number of moves(swaps) in Merge Sort [C++]

Tags: c++, sorting, mergesort

I am trying to count the number of swaps and comparisons in merge sort.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int comparisons = 0;
int moves = 0;

void merge(int arr[], int l, int m, int r)
{
    int i, j, k;
    int n1 = m - l + 1;
    int n2 = r - m;

    int* L = new int[n1];
    int* R = new int[n2];

    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
        L[i] = arr[l + i];
    for (j = 0; j < n2; j++)
        R[j] = arr[m + 1 + j];

    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    k = l;
    while (i < n1 && j < n2)
    {
        if (L[i] <= R[j])
        {
            arr[k] = L[i];
            moves++;
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            arr[k] = R[j];
            moves++;
            j++;
        }
        k++;
        comparisons++;
    }

    while (i < n1)
    {
        arr[k] = L[i];
        moves++;
        i++;
        k++;
    }

    while (j < n2)
    {
        arr[k] = R[j];
        moves++;
        j++;
        k++;
    }
}

void mergeSort(int arr[], int l, int r)
{
    if (l < r)
    {
        int m = l + (r - l) / 2;

        mergeSort(arr, l, m);
        mergeSort(arr, m + 1, r);

        merge(arr, l, m, r);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int size;
    cout << "Enter size: " << endl;
    cin >> size;

    int* arr = new int[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        arr[i] = rand() % 100;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }

    cout << endl << endl;

    mergeSort(arr, 0, size - 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }

    delete[] arr;

    cout << endl;

    cout << "The number of comparisons: " << comparisons << endl;
    cout << "The number of moves: " << moves << endl;

    cout << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

If I make an array of 10 elements, the number of comparisons should be 10 * log2(10) = 33 (formula: number of comparisons = n* log2n).And my program outputs 24, so it's incorrect.
Number of moves should be 2 * 10 * log2(10) = 66 (formula: number of moves= n* log2n).And my program outputs 34, so it's incorrect, as well.
Explain me please how to do it correctly. Where I made a mistake?

Comment: Have you tried running the program with a debugger, and seeing where in is counting these non-existent comparisons or moves?

Comment: What basis are you using for your expected counts?

Comment: Unrelated: I see `int* arr = new int[size];`, `int* L = new int[n1];` and `int* R = new int[n2];`, but I only see `delete[] arr;`

Comment: you confuse complexity with actual comparisons. `O(n log n)` is the average/worst case complexity. For example when the input is already sorted, then the number of swaps is much less

Comment: Yes, I have tried  running the program with a debugger, but I'm quite bad at this, so I haven't found any mistakes during debugging.

Comment: @idclev 463035818 So my answear is correct but if number of comparisons was > then 33, and number of moves > then 66 it would be wrong, have I understood it correctly?

Comment: not quite. you should reread complexity. It only tells you the asymptotic behavior, ie for large N. If an algorithm needs `N^2 + 100*N + 10000` operations, then its complexity is `O(N^2)`, but for small `N` only `N^2` will be much smaller than the actual number of operations

Comment: If anybody could rewrite this code correctly I would be really glad because I'm not competent in this topic

Answer (score 0):

As it has been said, you are confusing complexity with the number of executions of a concrete instruction. Let's take a look at this code snippet.
`

```
#include <iostream>
 #include <vector>
 using namespace std; //don't do this at home
 void exempleFunction(vector<int>& v){ //size of v is n
     for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){
         if (i==0){
             swap(v[0], v[1]);
         }
     }
 }
 int main(){
     int n;
     std::cin>>n;    //n > 1
     vector<int> v(n);
     readVector(n); //gets the values of the vector
     exempleFunction(v);
 }`
```

In this code, the cost of the exempleFunction() is O(n), and the number of times that swap is executed will be 1 regardless o n's value.
Having said that, lets take a look at this code:

```
``#include <iostream>
  #include <vector>
  using namespace std; //don't do this at home
  void exempleFunction(vector<int>& v){ //size of v is n
      for(int i = 1; i < v.size(); i++){
          swap(v[i], v[i-1]);
      }
  }
  int main(){
      int n;
      std::cin>>n;    //n > 1
      vector<int> v(n);
      readVector(n); //gets the values of the vector
      exempleFunction(v);
  }``
```

In this case the function swap() is executed n-1 times that is n-2 times more than in the previous case (just imagine if n is 1000000 how huge the difference is). However, the cost of the exempleFunction in still O(n)!
The same thing happens in your code, the cost of the function doesn't represent how many times a concrete method will be executed. The cost or complexity of a function is a way to measure the variation on the number of instruction executed based on the value of n. If you represent the number of instructions executed by your algorithm in function of the size of n your graph will behave aproximately as the cost of your algorithm does.